# How do you remove everything before and after a variable number on each line?

Tags: sed, replace, bioinformatics

I need to rename all of the sequence headers in a file.

The headers begin in this format:

```
>D915_04184 transcript=D915_04184 gene=D915_04184
```

Afterwards, they should just contain the sequence ID in this format:

```
D915_04184
```

And I need to do this for every sequence in the file.

I've been trying to use sed like

```
sed 's/'>D915' 'transcript=' 'gene='/D915/g' file_Name >new_file_name
```

But that has not worked. I've also tried to do `grep -o`, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Every so often I manage to take the `>` out of the very start but can’t seem to get rid of anything else. The `04184` needs to stay and that number is different on every line. The `>D915` is consistent.

Comment: What was your thought with respect to the single quotes in your `sed` attempt? Can you walk us through the steps you were attempting with the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -r 's/>//;s/\ .*//g' filename > new_file_name
```

I think you should take a look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to understand how `sed` works.

Comment: Thanks for this and thanks for the link. I definitely needed the link to work out how sed actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

if you want to keep the first part:

```
sed -E 's/(>D915_[0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/ >//g'
```

`()` <-- is used for remebering pattern 
`>D915_[0-9]+` <--  Means  string starting with D915_ followed by  any repetition of number.

Demo:

```
  $echo " >D915_04184 transcript=D915_04184 gene=D915_04184"  | sed -E 's/(>D915_[0-9]+).*/\1/g;s/ >//g' 
D915_04184
$
```

If `D915_` will also change then

```
sed 's/transcript.*//g; s/ >//g'
```

Demo :

```
$echo " >D915_04184 transcript=D915_04184 gene=D915_04184"  | sed 's/transcript.*//g; s/ >//g' 
D915_04184
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you might convert that input string to the output shown in your question. The one you choose might depend on variations to input that are not shown in the sample date you've provided.

You could remove everything in each line up to the last equals:

```
sed 's/.*=//'
```

Or you could remove everything after the first space, then strip the first character:

```
sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's/.//'
```

Or you could grab the content of the "transcript" field, and strip off the other bits:

```
sed -e 's/.*transcript=//' -e 's/ .*//'
```

I'm using the multiple `-e` notation for ease of reading. You could also write this last one more succinctly as:

```
sed 's/.*transcript=//;s/ .*//'
```

Comment: This really helps with the how this works exactly by breaking it into how youd adapt it to other problems. Thanks!